# I'm trying to perform the join function to get

Tags: python

```
def join_char(arr):
    join_chars = " "
    for i in join_chars:
        return join_chars


x = ["Kari", "can", "keep", "her", "car"]
print(join_char())
```

Expected: Kari, can, keep, her, car

Comment: Why do you expect that result from that function? Your function doesn't even do anything with its argument (`arr`).

Comment: There is a `join` function built in to Python:  print(`', '.join(x)`).  If you must write your own, then @Selcuk is right.  Your need to loop over the elements of `arr`, not the elements of `join_chars`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in function `join`:

```py
x = ['Kari', 'can', 'keep', 'her', 'car']
print(print(', '.join(x)))
# Output: Kari, can, keep, her, car
```

If you want to write your own function, you must loop through the input array and append each element along with `glue` string to the result string:

```py
def join_char(arr, glue = ' '):
    if not arr:
        return ''
    join_chars = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        join_chars += glue + arr[i]
    return join_chars

x = ['Kari', 'can', 'keep', 'her', 'car']
print(join_char(x, ', '))
# Output: Kari, can, keep, her, car
```

Answer (score 0):

def join_char(arr):
if not arr:
return ''
join_chars = arr[0] + ", "
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
join_chars += arr[i] + ", "
return join_chars

x = ['Kari', 'can', 'keep', 'her', 'car']
print(join_char(x, ', '))